# Sum function in R

Tags: r

I want to compute a simple sum, but not from 1 to the value that I put in the sum function, instead I want it to sum like I would normally do in math, where I have an expression which has some variable, that I then change from 1:4, and then R is suppose to sum the expression values.

Like

```
y = function(x) x**2

sum(y(x),x=3:5) = 3^2+4^2+5^2
```

How do I do this in R?

Answer (score 6):

You almost had it, just pass the `3:5` directly to `y`:

```
> y <- function(x) x**2
> sum(y(3:5))
[1] 50
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a custom function:

```
mysum <- function(f,vals) sum(f(vals))
mysum(y,3:5)
# [1] 50
```

While this is not standard in R, there are uses for passing function and arguments separately:

```
sapply(list(sqrt=sqrt,log=log,sin=sin),mysum,vals=1:3)
#     sqrt      log      sin 
# 4.146264 1.791759 1.891888
```

Answer (score 2):

If your function doesn't accept a vector, then you'll need to use an apply function. In base R:

```
y <- function(x) x^2
sum(sapply(1:4, y))
```

or

```
sum(Vectorise(y)(1:4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign the values to x beforehand and than sum the result of your function. So like this:

`y = function(x) x^2
x = 3:5
sum(y(x))`